# Counting the number of events in a logfile in a sliding time window

Tags: java, logging, data-structures

I have a log file of Apache Web Server on a Linux OS. Currently, I am interested in obtaining 100 frequent IP addresses, with their frequencies, connecting to my server in the last 5 minutes. For each of these IP addresses, I need to maintain a list of URLs they have visited with the frequency of visiting each URL. The way I have done this is as follows:

1- I have created a queue, adding each line with the its timestamp to its end.
2- At each epoch, e.g. 1 second, I check the log and add new ones with their timestamp, as well as checking the items at the front of queue, if their timestamp does not fall within 5 minutes from now, I will remove them from the queue.
3- I have created a dictionary, java hashmaps, with IP as key and value as an integer `count` and another hashmap containing URLs with counts (URL as key and count as value). Note that the value of the IP hashmap is a hashmap (URL hashmap) and a count.
4- Each Insertion to queue is consisted of adding/updating the values of the IP hashmap and then the corresponding URL hashmap.
5- Each deletion to queue is consisted of updating/removing the values of the IP hashmap and the corresponding URL hashmap.

This works, but I have two problems:

1- This operation, although for my case it is feasible, might not fit into the epoch of 1 second,
2- It consumes a great amount of memory!

I have also googled too much and have inspected retroactive data structures, aggregative data structures like Fenwick and etc. But they do not help.

Even keywords for more search are appreciated.
Thanks.